# Android SurfaceView IllegalArgumentException lockCanvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview, android-bitmap, illegalargumentexception

I'm working on a video into a [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html).
My goal is to get recurrent bitmaps of the running video.
Here is my Custom implementation:

```
private static final String TAG = "XXX";
private Activity activity;
private SurfaceHolder mSurface;
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private SurfaceHolder mActiveSurface;
public ImageView imageView;

boolean locked, locked1;
private boolean isCreated;


public AlphaSurfaceView(Context context,Activity activity) {
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    setWillNotDraw(false);
    this.activity = activity;
}

public AlphaSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

}

public AlphaSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}


@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //super.onDraw(canvas);
    if(isCreated){
        if(getHolder() != null && getHolder().getSurface().isValid()){
            Canvas c = null;
            try {
                if(!locked){
                    try {
                        c = getHolder().lockCanvas();
                        locked = true;
                    }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        locked = false;
                    }
                    BitmapDrawable bdrawable = new BitmapDrawable();
                    bdrawable.draw(c);
                }

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                locked = false;
            }finally {
                if(c != null && locked){
                    getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    locked = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
    invalidate();

}



@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mSurface = holder;
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), Uri.parse("XX"), mSurface);
    mActiveSurface = mSurface;
    try {
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mMediaPlayer.start();
                mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.isCreated = true;

}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    Log.d(TAG, "surfacechanged");

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mMediaPlayer.stop();
}

@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    mMediaPlayer.stop();
}
```

The problem is an IllegalArgumentException occured by the lockCanvas() method.

I tried many possibilities as:

- Adding some boolean (locked & creation of surfaceview)
- Test if surface is valid
- even add exported="true" in targeted activity in Manifest's xml

By the way the first idea was to use getDrawingCache() but even i added setCacheEnabled(true), the return was null.

So how to resolve this Exception or using another way to get each frame?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't draw on a Surface *and* send a video to it.  A Surface is the producer end of a producer-consumer pair, and you can only have one producer at a time.

The easiest way to have a Canvas overlap a SurfaceView Surface is to draw on the View part of the SurfaceView.  Send the video to the Surface, and use `onDraw()` (like a [custom view](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html)) to draw on the View.

Bear in mind that the Surface is a separate layer that sits behind the View UI layer, so you will need to draw on the View with transparency to see the Surface contents.

Another approach is to use multiple overlapping SurfaceViews, but this is less efficient and more limited.  An example with three overlapping Surfaces can be found in [Grafika's](https://github.com/google/grafika) multi-surface test Activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
surfaceHolder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            Log.e("video","surfaceChanged");
        }
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
            Log.e("video","surfaceCreated");
            mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        }
        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
            Log.e("video","surfaceDestroyed");
            if (mediaPlayer != null) mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    });
```

That should help.
Let the MediaPlayer do the drawing thing.